# I want to prove that $W^{3,1}$ is continuously embedded into $L^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to prove that $W^{3,1}$ is continuously embedded into $L^2$.
Here is my attempt. ($D^ng$ means that the n-th order partial derivatives)

$$ g \in W^{3,1}\;\;\text{iff}\;\; g \in L^1, Dg \in L^1, D^2 g \in L^1, D^3 g \in L^1.$$
$$ \text{If} \; g \in L^1, \; \text{then} \; g \in L^2. \; $$
$$ \text{Thus} \; W^{3,1} \subset L^2. $$
are these things above right?
And here is my question.
How can I prove that  $$ \text{for any}\;g \in W^{3,1}, \;\exists C \geqslant 0\;\text{s.$\,$t.}\; \|g\|_2 \leqslant C\|g\|_{3,1} $$

Comment: In general, $L^1$ is not even a subset of $L^2$.

Comment: @Thomas Then how can i conclude that $W^{3,1} \subset L^2$?

Comment: You need to use the fact that the weak derivatives are integrable. Is this homework? What did you learn about these spaces?

Comment: Regarding your last line: You need $ \exists C\;\forall g\; \|g\|_2 \le C\|g\|_{3,1}$.

Comment: It's $W^{3,1}$ of which open set?